# extjs filter autorelaod

Tags: extjs

In extjs gridfilters, the api states:

```
/**
     * @cfg {Boolean} autoReload
     * Defaults to true, reloading the datasource when a filter change happens.
     * Set this to false to prevent the datastore from being reloaded if there
     * are changes to the filters.  See {@link updateBuffer}.
     */
autoReload : true,
```

The question is: if you set autorelaod; flase, when is the store going to reload? There is no 'Go' button as far as i can see

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store will reload when you explicitly call `yourstore.load()`. You may not want to always reload a store based on one filter is changed. For instance, you may want to wait until a user changes many filters -- after which the user will click a button to apply them. At this point you would call `yourstore.load()` explicitly.